# Printing the next element if the previous element is in a list

Tags: python

I would like to reduce the following Python code.
I have one list and a few if statements.

```
a=[one, two, three, four]
```

```
if a[0] in b:
     print(a[1])
if a[1] in b:
     print(a[2])
if a[2] in b:
     print(a[3])
if a[3] in b:
     print(a[0])
```

How can I reduce this to two lines of code and still to run in sequence?
It will permit list a to be of "n" length and I will not have to add them individually.

Comment: This does not have enough context to be on topic. What are you actually trying to do with your application? Can you show your whole program?

Comment: `print([a[(i+1)%len(a)] for i in range(len(a)) if a[i] in b])`

Answer (score 1):

Firstly we can simply loop through `a` to get the values to check that are in `b`.
However we need to know the index so we can increment a value, `i`, whilst looping through `a`.

```py
i = 0
for value in a:
    if value in b:
        print(a[i + 1])
    i += 1
```

You should notice that this doesn't actually work. This is because on the last value of `a` we go out of bounds. To fix this we can simply use the modulo operator, `%`, to keep the value in bounds.

```py
i = 0
for value in a:
    if value in b:
        print(a[(i + 1) % len(a)])
    i += 1
```

From here we can use `enumerate` rather than increment `i` manually.
And we start `i` at 1 to remove the need for that `(i + 1)`.

```py
for i, value in enumerate(a, start=1):
    if value in b:
        print(a[i % len(a)])
```

From you have a couple of options.

- You can use `zip` with `itertools` to remove the need for `i % len(a)`. This isn't going to be nice to read but can be more performant.
- Use a comprehension to reduce this to one line of code.

However these are more advanced topics.

Comment: Thank you. But how can I do this in sequence? For example with a top "if" and keyboard confirmation. Press enter show first item then another enter the second etc?

Comment: @AndyAndy You have not coded that and so asking for that is off-topic and I will not answer. If you manage to do that by yourself then you can post a new question.